# Facebook Style multiple Profile Edit using jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, profile, edit

I am trying to create facebook style multiple textbox edit, but is'nt working.

```
 var inputId = '';
 var that = '';
 var data = '';
 $(".text_wrapper").live('click', function() {
    that = this;
    data=$(this).html();    
    inputId = '#'+$(this).next().attr("id");
    $(inputId).val(data);
    $(inputId).show();
    $(that).hide();
    $(inputId).focus();
 });

 $(inputId).live("mouseover", function(e){
    $(inputId).hide();$(that).show();
 });

 $(inputId).change(function() {
    $(inputId).hide();
    var boxval = $(inputId).val();
    var dataString = 'data='+ boxval;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $(that).html(boxval);
        $(that).show();
      }
    });
 });
```

Here goes html

```
    <div class="text_wrapper">1245</div><input id="3123" name="timeout" type="text" 
class="edit" size="20" value="" />

    <div class="text_wrapper">98745</div><input id="3122" name="timeout" type="text" 
class="edit" size="20" value="" />
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
 <div class="text_wrapper">1245</div>
 <input id="3123" name="timeout" type="text" class="edit" size="20" value="" />
 <div>

 <div>
 <div class="text_wrapper">98745</div>
 <input id="3122" name="timeout" type="text" class="edit" size="20" value="" />
 </div>




   jQuery(function(){

       //stpe 1
      jQuery('.text_wrapper').bind('mouseover',function(e){
             var elm = $(e.target);
             elm.hide();                     
            elm.parents('div:first')
           .find('input[type=text]').val(elm.html()).show()focus();              
       });

     //step 2
     //you should use 'blur' here rather than 'mouseover'
     // i have chosen mouseover as u have specified this in ur codes
      $('.edit').live("mouseover", function(e){
          var elm=$(e.target);
          elm.hide();
         elm.parents('div:first').find('.text_wrapper')
         .html(elm.val()).show();
       });

    //step 3
    // i dont think 'change' is good option, choose some other
    $('.edit').bind('change',function (e) {
        var elm = $(e.target);
        elm.hide();
        var boxval = elm.val();
        var dataString = 'data=' + boxval;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $(that).html(boxval);
                $(that).show();
            }
        });
    });


   });
```

Answer (score 0):

My better indenting shows at least one problem... try this:

```
 $(".text_wrapper").live('click', function() {
    that = this;
    data=$(this).html();    
    inputId = '#'+$(this).next().attr("id");
    $(inputId).val(data);
    $(inputId).show();
    $(that).hide();
    $(inputId).focus();

    $(inputId).live("mouseover", function(e){
      $(inputId).hide();$(that).show();
    });

    $(inputId).change(function() {
      $(inputId).hide();
      var boxval = $(inputId).val();
      var dataString = 'data='+ boxval;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $(that).html(boxval);
          $(that).show();
        }
      });
   });

 });
```

Note: This still has serious problems... on every click you are adding event handlers... they need to be cleared out before you set them up (at the least).  Or don't add the handlers in the click event.

Comment: exactly what i pointed out in any answer. in this corrected version, atleast the event handlers for the text divs which you recognize with "inputId" are within the function where you set them.

Answer (score 0):

One very apparent problem I see with the code is that inputId is set in the handler for the click on the div. You cannot use that variable to track clicks. Why don't you bind events to the edit class input boxes instead? Actually, I have no idea why you are keeping track of those inputIds in this piece of code.